# Is it possible to add a command at the beginning of a chapter?

Tags: etoolbox

I found the `etoolbox` package that allows me to add commands at the beginning of another command.

I tried the following but this does not work:

```
\apptocmd{\chapter}{
    \exewidth{(34)}
}
```

I want to reset a certain value at the beginning of every chapter with the call to `\exewidth`. How can this be done?

Comment: Real quick: `\apptocmd` takes four arguments. In the example you've just posted, there are only two arguments -- is this intentional?

Comment: If you're using titlesec, it's very easy, see page 4 in the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The definition of `\chapter` in the `book` class is

```
% book.cls, line 365:
\newcommand\chapter{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
                    \thispagestyle{plain}%
                    \global\@topnum\z@
                    \@afterindentfalse
                    \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
```

If you do

```
\apptocmd{\chapter}{
    \exewidth{(34)}
}{}{}
```

(note the two trailing arguments, look at the documentation of `etoolbox` for a description), you make the command `\secdef` to fail.

You're also adding unwanted spaces, but that's a minor detail.

The proper place to add `\exewidth` is at the *start*:

```
\pretocmd{\chapter}{% <--- IMPORTANT
    \exewidth{(34)}% <--- IMPORTANT
}{}{}
```

but, of course, this would add the setting also when `\chapter*` is called. In case you want it only for numbered chapters, the right command to patch is `\@chapter`, again with `\pretocmd`.

---

Suppose you add `\exewidth{(34)}` at the end. When `\secdef` is executed, it absorbs its two arguments (in this case `\@chapter` and `\@schapter`) and looks for a following `*`; there's no `*`, because the next token is `\exewidth`, so, according to its definition, `\secdef` delivers `\@dblarg{\@chapter}`. Note that `\exewidth` has only been examined, but is still in the input stream.

Now `\@dblarg` is executed; its action consists first in looking whether `[` follows. No, there's `\exewidth`; good, so look for an argument (represented by `#1`) and do `\@chapter[#1]{#1}`.

What's `#1`? Usually it would be the chapter title, if you type `\chapter{Title}`. But here there's still the `\exewidth` token pending. No brace, so `\exewidth` becomes `#1`.

Is this what you want? `;-)`

Comment: Thanks! Why does it have to go to the start?

Comment: @StefanMüller I added some explanations

Comment: Thanks! I start to understand some facts about the inner mechanics!