# How to add code at beginning of every chapter?

Tags: chapters, patching

I would like to add code at the beginning of every chapter. In particular, the `\minitoc` command. I hoped `\appto` would do the trick. But no luck.

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\appto\chapter{Test}
```

Just uses **T** as the chapter title and **est** after the chapter.

Using `\apptocmd` does not work either. I looked, for example, at [Is it possible to add a command at the beginning of a chapter?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/298031). Unfortunately, its title is misleading, I think.

Here is a complete example:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\appto\chapter{Test}

\begin{document}

\chapter{One}

\end{document}
```

Which renders as

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\chapter` is just a top level command, it actually doesn't take any argument, neither does it typeset anything. It just takes LaTeX to the correct page (recto/verso) and sets the page style and some other minor things, then it calls `\@chapter` or `\@schapter`, depending if you used `\chapter` or `\chapter*` (all of this for the `book` class; other classes might behave differently). The fact that `\chapter` doesn't take arguments, make so that if you append `Test` to its definition, is the same as if you did:

```
\chapter Test{One}
```

and that's why the chapter title becomes `T` and the rest (`estOne`) is typeset below it. Which is what egreg meant in his answer (in the post you linked) with:

> If you do
>
> ```latex
> \apptocmd{\chapter}{
>     \exewidth{(34)}
> }{}{}
> ```
>
> (note the two trailing arguments, look at the documentation of `etoolbox` for a description), you make the command `\secdef` to fail.

He also gives a thorough explanation of what happens at the end of his answer.

You need to patch the inner `\@chapter` (and `\@schapter` if you want `\chapter*` too), which writes stuff to the table of contents and sets page headings, or yet, to `\@makechapterhead` (and `\@makeschapterhead`) which is the macro which does the actual typesetting of the chapter heading, depending on what exact effect do you want.

You were also missing the `success` and `failure` branches of `\apptocmd` which are used if the patching succeeded or failed.

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\apptocmd\@chapter % or \@makechapterhead
  {Test}
  {}{\FAILED}
% \apptocmd\@schapter % or \@makeschapterhead
%   {Test}
%   {}{\FAILED}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\chapter{One}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: I would skip `\appto\@schapter`, since the point of `\chapter*` is not NOT appear in the TOC.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Depends on what one wants to append to the command. But indeed, OP said he wants a `\minitoc`, so I guess you're right. Thanks!