# enotez: listing chapter or section names at the listing of endnotes

Tags: sectioning, enotez

From an MWE like this:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[backref,totoc=chapter,counter-format=Roman,split=chapter]{enotez}
\setenotez{split-title={\chaptername\ <ref>}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
Some text with an endnote.\endnote{Once upon a time\dots}

\printendnotes
\end{document}
```

I get the following:

[image]

Is there a way to get the chapter name also? Ie: `Chapter 1 -- Introduction`. I found [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/394456/access-chapter-or-section-title), but it only works within the current chapter or section... The enotez manual has also not been of much help...

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a non-obvious solution which relies on `nameref` and redefines `\chapter` in order to automatically place a label after it which can then be used.  Please note that this only works if all your endnotes are in *numbered* chapters…

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{enotez}
\setenotez{
  backref,
  totoc=chapter,
  counter-format=Roman,
  split=chapter,
  split-title={\chaptername\ <ref> -- <title>}
}

\NewSplitTitleTag{title}{\nameref{ch:<split-level-id>}}

\usepackage{nameref}% automatically loaded if you use hyperref

\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\LetLtxMacro\origchapter\chapter
\RenewDocumentCommand\chapter{som}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {% starred chapter, no label then
      \origchapter*{#3}%
    }
    {% else add a label
      \IfNoValueTF{#2}
        {\origchapter{#3}}
        {\origchapter[#2]{#3}}%
      \expanded{\noexpand\label{ch:\arabic{chapter}}}%
    }%
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
Some text with an endnote.\endnote{Once upon a time\dots}

\chapter{Second Chapter}
Some text with an endnote.\endnote{Twice upon a time\dots}

\chapter{And another one}
Some text with an endnote.\endnote{Another endnote\dots}

\printendnotes

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This was *almost* it, but it added needless "Chapter" to the Notes chapter (as well as the toc). The solution was to redefine chapter like this (requires etoolbox; snatched from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/298031/is-it-possible-to-add-a-command-at-the-beginning-of-a-chapter)):

`\makeatletter
\apptocmd{\@chapter}{%
  \expanded{\noexpand\label{ch:\arabic{chapter}}}%
}{}{}
\makeatother`

Comment: The suggestion in my previous comment works only for numbered chapters, but to me, this is not a problem.

Comment: @wmnorth see edited answer

Comment: Even though I prefer my alternative -- rather than redefining \chapter -- I have accepted your answer, as it does what I had asked for. Still... is there a reason to prefer redefining \chapter rather than patching (appending) to its definition? Or is it just a matter of taste?

Comment: @wmnorthit it isn't that important. I like it better if I don't have to rely about how things are implemented… :)